# Python: How to print two list verticle align in console

Tags: python, string, printing, console

For example, I got two lists, and here is my normal print when they got such elements.

```
arr = [100, -23, -23, 404, 100, 23, 23, 23, 3, 404]
mem = [0, 10, 10, 10, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

However, I want them print like this:

```
arr = [100, -23, -23, 404, 100, 23, 23, 23,  3, 404]
mem = [  0,  10,  10,  10,   1, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10]
```

Does anyone know how to print like this?

Try:
Search the Str.format(), print("".join("{} {}".formate( )) something like this.
but these are not correct formate for me.

Expectation:
I hope I can get a function like C++ setwidth() something.
Thx

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track: you want to apply `{:3}` format specifier on each element of the array.

```
arr = [100, -23, -23, 404, 100, 23, 23, 23, 3, 404]
mem = [0, 10, 10, 10, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]

def format_list(l, f):
    es = ", ".join(f.format(e) for e in l)
    return f"[{es}]"

print(f"arr = {format_list(arr, '{:3}')}")
print(f"mem = {format_list(mem, '{:3}')}")
# => [100, -23, -23, 404, 100,  23,  23,  23,   3, 404]
#    [  0,  10,  10,  10,   1,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10]
```

Comment: Appreciate your help.
Your code is elegant. I am a beginner, it's a little hard for me to read and understand.

Comment: Appreciate your help.
I am a Python beginner compared to you. 
Could you help me rewrite the format_list function step by step rather than combine all of them? 
`res = []
for element in arr:
    res.append("{:3}".format(element))
    print(f"res = {res}")`
I tried to convert it to step-by-step, but I couldn't do that. I would like to know why you 'return f"[{es}]"' like this format.

Comment: What do you mean, "I couldn't do that"? Your code is fine, up to constructing a list of formatted elements. The missing thing is to join the formatted elements using `join`: `", ".join(res)`, and add brackets at the start and end (which is the purpose of my ` f"[{es}]"`).